# My Flutter app can't stay portraitUp even though I have added the necessary codes

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

```
 void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized;
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I add this section to "main.dart" but it didn't work on Samsung Phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setPreferredOrientation is async, i think the issue might be that the app run before setPreferredOrientation is finished. Try using the "then" function to run the app after the function is done. Like this :

```
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then(
  (value) => runApp(const MyApp()));
```